# Execute postgres trigger after 24 hours after record insertion?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I`m trying to execute trigger after 24 hours after record insertion, for each row, how to do this? please help

you know, if user doesn`t verificate his email, his account will be deleted.

Without cron and so on.

Postgres db. PostgreSQL

Comment: why won't you use cron? It's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

This may help In relation to scheduling an sql command to run at a certain time.

[PGagent](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php)

This is the command I tested and you could use this in **PGagent**.

```
delete from email_tbl where email_id in(select email_id from email_tbl 
where timestamp < now() - '1 day'::interval );
```

Here is the test data i used.

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;

CREATE DOMAIN email_addr AS citext
CHECK(
VALUE ~ '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$' 
);


CREATE TABLE email_tbl (
email_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
email_addr email_addr NOT NULL UNIQUE,
timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

And here's some test data

```
insert into email_tbl (email_addr) values('me@home.net')

insert into email_tbl (email_addr,timestamp)
values('me2@home.net','2015-07-15 00:00:00'::timestamp)

select * from email_tbl where timestamp < now() - '1 day'::interval
```

All the best